# How to deploy multiple artifacts to nexus?

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I'm using Nexus Artifact Upload in jenkins pipeline to upload artifacts to Nexus, in the pipeline I'm using this code to deploy, it works perfectly for deploying one artifact. but how can I deploy multipe artifacts :

```
Stage 'Nexus Deploy'
     nexusArtifactUploader
        artifactId: 'com.example.project',
        file: 'server/jetty-project/target/jetty-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war',
        groupId: 'test-javaproject',
        type:'war',
        nexusPassword: 'admin123',
        nexusUrl: 'XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/nexus',
        nexusUser: 'admin',
        nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
        protocol: 'http',
        repository: 'maven-snapshots',
        version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

in the doc it says that it's possible to deploy multiple artifacts like that

```
freeStyleJob('NexusArtifactUploaderJob') {
    steps {
      nexusArtifactUploader {
        nexusVersion('nexus2')
        protocol('http')
        nexusUrl('localhost:8080/nexus')
        groupId('sp.sd')
        version('2.4')
        repository('NexusArtifactUploader')
        credentialsId('44620c50-1589-4617-a677-7563985e46e1')
        artifact {
            artifactId('nexus-artifact-uploader')
            type('jar')
            classifier('debug')
            file('nexus-artifact-uploader.jar')
        }
        artifact {
            artifactId('nexus-artifact-uploader')
            type('hpi')
            classifier('debug')
            file('nexus-artifact-uploader.hpi')
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering how to make that in the jenkinsfile ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find the below syntax for the nexusArtifactUploader in Jenkinsfile.

```
nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [
   [artifactId: 'nexus-artifact-uploader', classifier: 'debug', file: 'nexus-artifact-uploader.jar', type: 'jar'], 
   [artifactId: 'nexus-artifact-uploader', classifier: 'debug', file: 'nexus-artifact-uploader.hpi', type: 'hpi']
], 
credentialsId: '44620c50-1589-4617-a677-7563985e46e1', 
groupId: 'sp.sd', 
nexusUrl: 'localhost:8080/nexus', 
nexusVersion: 'nexus2', 
protocol: 'http', 
repository: 'NexusArtifactUploader', 
version: '2.4'
```

You can generate the above syntax from the pipeline snippet generator.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with deploying `${artifactName}.jar` and `${artifactName}-sources.jar` artifacts to the same Nexus directory using **Nexus Jenkins Plugin**.

The problem was with the same packaging type (`jar`), that's why these artifacts couldn't be uploaded to Nexus: plugin changes both provided file names to `${artifactId}-${version}.${packaging}` and I've got the error:

> Upload component was unsuccessful (400 response from server)

Fixed the issue by providing `classifier` for `-sources.jar` artifact:

```
stage('Publish') {
    def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
    nexusPublisher nexusInstanceId: 'your-nexus-instance-id', \
        nexusRepositoryId: 'your-nexus-repository-id', \
        packages: [[$class: 'MavenPackage', \
        mavenAssetList: [[classifier: '', extension: '', filePath: "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}.${pom.packaging}"], \
                         [classifier: 'sources', extension: '', filePath: "target/${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}-sources.${pom.packaging}"]], \
        mavenCoordinate: [artifactId: "${pom.artifactId}", \
        groupId: "${pom.groupId}", \
        packaging: "${pom.packaging}", \
        version: "${pom.version}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"]]]
}
```